# How to move huge popup window in Yosemite?

Tags: google-chrome, window-manager

After upgrading to Yosemite / Chrome updating (one of these two), I have difficulties to submit files via Google Chrome because the popup window for submitting is huge and lower buttons cannot be seen at all. The only way to operate that - double click on the file (I found that after some days!).

Look at the screenshot - it is the lower visible part of the popup window, but it is not a lower border of this window.

[image]

Is there any way to resize/move this window?

Comment: @Tetsujin Probably. Fullscreen helped! 10x.

Comment: I added a new method to that answer - Alternatively, if you Cmd/Shift/drag from any edge of the 'parent' window, the window will resize from all sides simultaneously.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ironically, I've tried all these buttons and the issue resolved completely - all new popup windows are smaller.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've voted up your answer on the link provided...

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with Google Chrome:

- Issue 150068: "Save as" modal sheet sometimes not sized correctly

  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=150068

As a workaround, you can go fullscreen then open the sheet—this forces it to fit on the screen.

Comment: but can I move or resize that window?

Comment: @Ilan I've added a workaround—standard OS X sheets *should* fit the screen when fullscreen.

Comment: Fullscreen helped. Should I delete the question?

Comment: @Ilan No need—it serves as another pointer to the resolution with completely different keywords, very useful for others looking for a solution.

Comment: I found the definite solution and the issue resolved completely - I resized the left border pressing Shift and the window minimized. Now, new popup are smaller and visible fully.

Comment: @Ilan Interesting! Feel free to add that as an answer here or on the linked question so that it gets more visibility.

Comment: hhh ironically the same answer was suggested in comments to the question...

Comment: @grgarside Can this question remain open, even linked as a dupe? - as you say, the keywords would make the solution easier to find if both remained active.

Comment: @Tetsujin Not sure I understand what you mean—linking it as a duplicate will prevent new answers (closing it) but it still exists and is searchable to direct users.

Comment: OK, no problem then. I'm still a bit of a newbie on exactly where old questions go to die ;-)